# Can I prevent a dependency change from rebuilding a Flutter widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I know that any dependency change will rebuild a widget after firing `didChangeDependencies`.

Is there a way of preventing the Widget from rebuilding?

I can see that `didChangeDependencies` returns `void` when maybe if should return a `boolean` in order to cancel a rebuild?

But is there another way of stopping the widget rebuilding?

(yes I know, the smart answer will be - "if it's a dependency then it should build, otherwise it's not a dependency", but just humour/humor me ok )

Comment: hmmm, `build()` method is like paying taxes, you cannot avoid it and have to be prepared for it at anty time ;-) - but seriously whats the problem with `build()` method called multiple times?

Comment: Problem is that my widget is a `SingleChildScrollView` and every time the widget rebuilds it moved the scroll to the top, so it's juddery and not great UX. (though there's probably a switch in the `SingleChildScrollView` to prevent that, but...)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. yes that is a 'SingleChildScrollView` but my build is being triggered when a dependency (a service widget receiving a Stream) is rebuilding, not a call to `setState` from within the widget itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [`updateShouldNotifyDependent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedModel/updateShouldNotifyDependent.html) method is what you want

Comment: If I was using an `InheritedModel`then maybe. it might be a solution but at the moment I don't want to refactor my code just to fix what seems a trivial issue. But thanks.